# Microsoft Academic - how to encode query

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

How would one encode a query for alzheimer's disease? The open API testing console does not appear to handle this correctly, neither for evaluate nor for interpret.

Answer (score 0):

All academic entity names are normalized to remove case and special characters. The evaluate method does not account for this, so you'd need to know the normalized entity name before requesting said entity.

However the interpret method *does* account for this and automatically normalizes all queries. I was able to enter "alzheimer's disease" in the [interpret API test console](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/56332331778daf06340c9666/console) and get the appropriate interpretation (which contains the query expression you'd send to the evaluate method to get full entity results).